# How to record audio in Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, audio, recording

I want to record audio in wave format in angular using typescript how can I achieve it ? I tried several solutions like RecorderJS, RecordRTC but nothing worked out.

Comment: Please post the code and a description how it didn't work and the exact error messages. There is nothing special about that in Angular. Angular runs in the browser and executes JavaScript like any web application.

Comment: I was able to record audio and play it from JS but failed to access that audio data in typescript code. But now I made some changes stored it in a global variable and now its working fine. Also thanks for quick response.

Comment: @VishalHulawale, since you've gotten your problem working, do you mind letting me know which you used/prefered RecorderJS vs RecordRTC?

Comment: I used RecorderJS as my requirement was to record audio in wav format with provided sample rate.

Comment: @VishalHulawale, What are the steps you have followed to achieve the audio recorder in angular 2. Can you explain it briefly or create a new question with Own answer or  can you send the solution via email. I'm also having this requirement.